# Как добавить в access.log миллисекунды?

Tags: nginx, дата, время

Я хочу, чтобы к дате `30/Apr/2018:20:32:45` подписывались еще миллисекунды.
В документации есть переменная `$time_local`, которая не пишет миллисекунды и есть `$msec`, которая содержит `timestamp` вместо нормальной даты.
Как мне получить дату в нормальном виде с миллисекундами?
Что для этого нужно прописать в директиву `log_format`?

Comment: Создать переменную с нужным значением и логировать её.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, такой возможности у nginx нет. Подробности - в документации и [на ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/732395/can-nginx-log-time-in-iso-8601-format-but-include-milliseconds)